# What's the difference between Rails' cache stores?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3, caching

What's the difference between Rails 3's multiple cache stores? Specifically

- Rails.application.config.cache_store
- ActionController::Base.cache_store

Comment: This is well explained here http://guides.rubyonrails.org/v2.3.11/caching_with_rails.html

Comment: @Pavan, no it's not. That article describes different types of cache stores (E.g. memory_store, file_store, etc), but doesn't explain how Rails.application.config.cache_store differs from ActionController::Base.cache_store .

Answer (score 0):

Typically they don't differ. As far as I know, `ActionController::Base.cache_store` uses `Rails.application.config.cache_store` unless it's otherwise told not to.

Comment: That's not my experience. When I set `Rails.application.config.cache_store` to `redis_store` and don't set `ActionController::Base.cache_store`, the latter is set to `file_store` and view fragments are cached using `file_store`. When I swap the values, view fragments are cached using `redis_store`.